# co-occurence and mutual exclusivity of two events

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I would like to compute co-occurence and mutual exclusivity for a set of events divided in two groups (A and B). Each event `E_{x,y}` represents if a mutation occurs in the gene `x` from sample `y` These two groups of events are encoded in two matrix (A and B) with the same number of columns and rows ( columns = samples ; rows = genes). Cell values can either by 1 (mutation occurs) or 0 (no mutation occurs). A_{x,y} represent an event of type A for gene x from sample y. B_{k,l} represents an event of type B for gene k and l.

I would like to test co-occurence or mutual exclusivity for each pair of genes. Thus comparing each pair of `A_{i,.}` ; `B_{i,.}` where `i` is `1..number of genes`.

Is a fisher exact test a good option ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Fisher exact test seems a reasonable option to me. For each gene you have a 2x2 table with for numbers of occurences (A and B, A and not B, not A and B, not A and not B). The odds ratio (together with the p-value) will tell you whether you have co-occurences or mutual exclusivity.

Comment: Ok thank you. And is fisher test ok if there is might be a causality effect between events from group A to B. So to check if event A_{x,.} is = 1 is there some event B more prone to be 1 ( or 0 )

Comment: No, the the Fisher test does not tell you anything about causality. It can be that A causes B, that B causes A or that another cause C causes both A and B.

Comment: ok thank you. Reading a little bit about testing causality and indeed it's not trivial ..